# How to create polygon and calculate area of ocean within a circle on a map

Tags: r, geospatial

I have a map with a circle drawn around a point. Part of the circle covers land and part of it covers ocean. I want to calculate the area of ocean within the circle, but I don't know how to create that polygon. The code for the map with the circle is

```
library(dismo)
library(scales)
library(rgeos)

GI <- gmap("Grand Isle,Louisiana", zoom = 7, scale = 2)
d <- data.frame(lat = c(29.2278), lon = c(-90.0122))
coordinates(d) <- ~ lon + lat
projection(d) <- "+init=epsg:4326"
d_mrc <- spTransform(d, CRS = CRS(projection(GI)))
d_mrc_bff <- gBuffer(d_mrc, width = 100000)

plot(GI)
plot(d_mrc_bff, col = alpha("blue", .35), add = TRUE)
points(d_mrc, cex = 2, pch = 20)
```

I have looked into `mask`{raster} and `landmask`{GSIF} functions, but I think in my case it won't work since I only want to mask the land within the circle, not on the entire map. Or I don't really need to mask it, but create the polygon with boundaries being the perimeter of the circle and the coastline.
Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: BTW, if you want a more "circular" circle, just increase the value of `quadsegs` in your call to `gBuffer()`. And, to learn the number of pixels of each type (including the ocean, here coded as having value 178) that fall within that polygon, you could use `raster::extract(GI, d_mrc_bff)`. (The area of each pixel is returned by `prod(res(GI))`.)

Comment: Great, thanks for that tip! I will try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(rgdal)

# US States outlines
URL <- "http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json"
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

# extract Louisiana
us <- readOGR(fil, "OGRGeoJSON")
la <- subset(us, NAME=="Louisiana")

# have to re-project d_mrc_bff or la, I chose the former

plot(gDifference(spTransform(d_mrc_bff, proj4string(la)), la), col="steelblue")
```

[image]
You can use `gArea` to get the area of that.

You can use higher resolution source shapefiles if you need better boundaries for more precision in your area.

h/t to Josh O'Brien for catching my use of `gIntersection` vs `gDifference`.

Comment: ARGH. yep. totally my bad. I got too focused on "mask the land in the circle".  I'll add that.

Comment: Thanks again, the rest of the solution works but the last line of code 
`plot(gDifference(spTransform(d_mrc_bff, proj4string(la)), la), col="steel blue")` gives an error message:
 
Error in plot(gDifference(spTransform(d_mrc_bff, proj4string(la)), la),  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': Error in spTransform(d_mrc_bff, proj4string(la)) : 
  second argument needs to be of class CRS

This is strange since it seems to have worked in the solution!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried to re-project la also but I still get the same error message

Comment: I changed the last line of code to `plot(gDifference(spTransform(d_mrc_bff, CRS=CRS(proj4string(la))), la), col="steel blue")`

and now it works. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @user3281487 Glad to hear this helped. If this answered your question, it's good practice to indicate that by clicking the checkmark immediately to its left. Cheers.